# About the cardinality of the Borelians in the real line.

Tags: set-theory

Is true that the set of the Borelians in $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$? I need of the Continuum Hypothesis for to prove this?

Comment: What do you mean by Borelians? Do you mean Borel sets?

Comment: Yes, this is true, and no, the continuum hypothesis is not needed. It is also true that every Borel set either is countable or has the size of the reals (in fact, contains a perfect subset), and no, the continuum hypothesis is not needed to show this either, but the axiom of choice is required.